# Inject several parameters from parameters.ini to a service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am looking for a BEAUTIFUL way to send several parameters from parameters.ini to a service.

Actually to send 10 parameters to my service, I need 10 arguments in my constructor and that's not very beautiful. My code really starts at line 350 (with all attributes and docs) and I'm unsatisfied with that.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299981/symfony2-how-to-inject-all-parameters-in-a-service) answer, I can inject the @kernel service but that's quite a bad practice.

Do you have some advices about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass a single argument as associative array of more services and parameters.

Comment: It works, thanks :-) For someone who reads and don't understand, the way is to inject `[%param1%, %param2%, ...]` instead of `%param1%, %param2%...`. You finally get a single array with your properties in the same order as your declaration in the services.yml.