# Symfony2 - use parameters on config.yml for the arguments of a service

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use the method described on this other question and I wasn't able to make it work:

[Symfony2: How to inject ALL parameters in a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299981/symfony2-how-to-inject-all-parameters-in-a-service#answer-25559656)

In summary, I would like to define the arguments of my service in a unique file using a variable. I would then only pass this variable as an argument to my service. If one day, I decide to change the arguments, I don't have to change all the calls on my service. I would just change the content of this variable. However, I'm having the following error:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to other services (reference to service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager" found in "/company.usermanagerservice/em").

Was anybody able to make it work? Or do you have other ideas?

### Edit:

```
services.yml: 
    company.user_manager: 
        class: Company\CoreBundle\Model\UserManager 
        arguments: [%company.userManagerService%]
```

Then on config.yml:

```
parameters: 
    company.userManagerService: 
        em: 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager' 
        user_helper: 'company.helper.user' 
        fos_manipulator: 'fos_user.util.user_manipulator'
```

Comment: Please add your configuration, how is `/headoo.usermanagerservice/em` defined?

Comment: I tried on services.yml:  company.user_manager:    class: Company\CoreBundle\Model\UserManager    arguments: [%company.userManagerService%]  Then on config.yml:  parameters:      company.userManagerService:    em: 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager'    user_helper: 'company.helper.user'    fos_manipulator:    'fos_user.util.user_manipulator'

Comment: Sorry I'm not managing to make mini-Markdown work. It's kind of illegible.

Comment: Fixed that for you ;)